# Puppet/Foreman - Hostgroups and classes

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, foreman, puppet-foreman

I successfully set up foreman and puppet. Now I'm trying to configure `host groups` which should contain a specific configuration.

My example: Host group "Basic" should get a special MOTD.

I installed a MOTD-module for puppet:

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-motd
```

Now I imported the class to foreman - works also fine.

Next step was adding a new host group:

[image: New host group]

Okay, fine. Now I'm adding my new motd-class:
[image: Class]

Okay, now it would be fine if all hosts belonging to the host group "Basis" would show a MOTD-text "Hello World". If I configure another host group "Test" which is also using the motd-module the text should be "Bye, bye world".

How can I specify parameters for each host group this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motd module you downloaded has a "content" parameter on the motd class that controls what's in the /etc/motd file.  This is shown at https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/motd#usage.

By default, Foreman doesn't set the value of any class parameters.  Go to *Configure > Puppet classes* (sorry, you'll have to translate to German), click on the class and go to the *Smart class parameters* tab.

The known (imported) smart class parameters are listed on the left, click `content`, tick the *Override* checkbox and either enter a default value for it or tick the *Use Puppet default* box if you prefer.

When editing a host or host group with the class assigned, the content parameter will now be listed on the *Parameters* tab and can be overridden.  Click the override button to set a value on the host group and save it.  Host overrides take precedence over a host group override.

More information on these overrides is in the [Smart Matchers](http://theforeman.org/manuals/latest/index.html#4.2.6SmartMatchers) part of the Foreman manual.  They can be configured in more detail on the Puppet classes page above.